# Eclipse, PyDev, Kivy in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, pydev, kivy

I am new to Eclipse and PyDev.

I have installed Eclipse, Pydev and Kivy under Ubuntu 12.01.

I created a new Pydev Project in Eclipse. Now I want to use Kivy(and or xxWidgets) in it.

How can I set this configuration in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

-Install Python. I am using python 2.7 so : `sudo apt-get install python2.7`

-Install the latest stable builds :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python-kivy
```

-If you want to install examples of kivy apps :

```
sudo apt-get install python-kivy-examples
```

If you have a problem with pydev, close eclipse, run it as root, re-install pydev from eclipse repos . Restart eclipse normally(without root), and it will work fine .

If you have problems with eclipse automatic save/logging , give the rights to the actual user to write in the file/folder (may be in `~/.eclipse/someOtherFolders/File...`) mentioned in the error box with `chmod` (-R if it is a folder).