# Kivy development in eclipse PyDev on Ubuntu 14.04 SetUp

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, kivy, pydev

I begun to develope with Python and Kivy and I really like it :-) For daily business I'm a Java developer and also a an eclipse child. So i decided to setup eclipse (Mars) with Python, means install PyDev-Plugin and create the settings (done in one button-click).

But I have a problem, my eclipse do not want to recognize the kv-files as python files.

So my question has anyone experience with this set up?
Do anyone knows a good set up tutorial?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe this answer could help: [eclipse automatic save/logging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20001684/5296404)

Answer (score 2):

*.kv files *aren't* Python files.  I don't think trying to treat them as such is really what you want to do.  If you must, you can choose to treat *.kv files as python files by going to Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations and adding an entry for *.kv with the Python Editor as an associated editor.

My own personal preference, however, is to use YEdit YAML editor for *.kv files.  It won't recognize Python syntax in expressions, but it works well enough for me.  If you're willing to use an external editor, you can get Kv-lang syntax highlighting in Vim.  If you're willing to learn to use Vim.  Which you should, because Vim is awesome.

Finally, if you're willing to pay, the developer of PyDev also develops a closed source fork of Eclipse called Liclipse, which, if I recall correctly, has syntax highlighting, outlining, and autocomplete in kv files.

Comment: Thx Will, for .kv I use now sublime. Also very nice :-)